# Find the interest rate, given the increase over the period of 9 months

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

Goods were bought for Rs. 600 and sold the same for Rs. 688.50 at a credit of 9 months and thus gaining 2% The rate of interest per annum is

A.$16\ ^2/_3\ \%$ B. $14\ ^1/_2\ \%$ C. $13\ ^1/_3\ \%$ D. $15\ \%$

First, please explain me the question, I didn't get the thus gaining 2% part.

Comment: This is a little off topic, it is more finance/economics.

Comment: No, it's a maths question.

Comment: @ErikMiehling it is in Indian curriculum of mathematics for children around 12-13

Answer (score 1):

Selling Price
$$S.P.=102\%\times600=612 $$
 
Present Worth$$P.W.=612$$ and Sum$$S=688.5$$
True Discount$$T.D.=688.5-612=76.5$$
Thus, Simple Interest on $Rs. 612$ for $9$ months is $Rs. 76.50$

Therefore, Rate
$$R=\frac{100\times76.5}{612\times\frac34}=16\frac23\%$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\mbox{Every month you pay}\quad
600\,{r/1200 \over 1 - \pars{1 + r/1200}^{-9}} = {688.50 \over 9}
$$

> $$
> \mbox{From this equation, we'll get}\
> \approx 34.13\ \%\ \mbox{per annum}.
> $$